24.04 install failure
installing Ubuntu 24.04 Its , Unlock encrypted hd ok, but stops at splash screen before asking for p/w, I went into recovery, ran file check, gives this: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg -ubuntu--lv is mounted & cant continue.
